# Ember transition to route on parent dynamic segments (slugs)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, transition

I have this current `router.js` set up.

```
this.resource('parent', {path:'parent/:id'},function() {
  this.route('child', {path:'child/:name'});
});
```

Pages that are valid are `www.x.com/parent/5/child/jimmy` and `www.x.com/parent/5`

Using `this.transitionToRoute('parent.child','jimmy');` will get me to this page `www.x.com/parent/5/child/jimmy`.

Using `this.transitionToRoute('parent','5');` will get me to this page `www.x.com/parent/5`.

Since this route is nested, the `:id` parameter has an effect on the child route...

How could I transition to `www.x.com/parent/100/child/jimmy`? This is an update in the parent's dynamic segment `:id` while maintaining child dynamic segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.transitionToRoute('parent.child', '100', 'jimmy');
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute

"Multiple models will be applied recursively last to first up the resource tree."